# Force show back button in UINavigationBar without Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `View Controller` that has a `UINavigationBar` in it and I want to show the back button in the nav bar. The reason I am using a `View Controller` instead of a `Navigation Controller` is because of a custom animation I am using to switch between views. The back button will be used to start the back animation from the second view.

in any event is there any way I can force show the back button in the `UIViewController` with the Nav bar in it without creating an icon to use in a `UIBarButtonItem`

Answer (score 3):

Are you animating actual views, or are they `ViewController`s? Animating between viewControllers is perfectly doable using a navigation controller and writing a custom segue. Then there's no trouble of adding a custom back button.

The only disadvantage using a custom segue is that the animation on the navigationBar is gone, resulting in a sudden 'change' of title and appearance of the back button.

Anyway, you could add your own button to the `navigationBar` using the following code:

```
yourNavigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonPressed)];
```

Don't forget to implement the `backButtonPressed` method.
It doesn't include the typical 'back' arrow, but you can solve this by adding an image to the button, or just by creating a custom view and include that in the navBar.

Comment: it is an animation between ViewControllers and this is the example http://zappdesigntemplates.com/uiviewcontroller-transition-from-uicollectionviewcell/ I just dont know how I can achieve the same thing with a segue